# Convergence in probability for a particular sequence of r.v.'s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Given the sequence of random variables $\{X_n: n \ge 1\} $ characterized by
$P[X_n = 1/n] = 1 - 1/n^2 $ and $P[X_n = n] = 1/n^2, $ I wanted to prove certain convergence results. It is not difficult to show that $X_n $ does not converge in L2 to any constant. But, how does one deal with convergence in probability? 
I am used to the example where $ P[Z_n=0] = 1-1/n^2 $ and $P[Z_n=n] = 1/n^2 $ in which case one shows that $Z_n \stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow} 0, $ but for the example given my usual setup to prove convergence in probability runs into some issues.   When I write $P[X_n > \epsilon], $ then the value of this probability depends on whether $n $ is such that 1/n < \epsilon $ or not.

Clearly, one can prove that $Y_n := X_n - 1/n  \stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow} 0. $ Still, proving or disproving convergence in probability to $0, $ for my original sequence of random variables, $\{X_n: n \ge 1\}, $ which I think is the only possibility of convergence in probability, escapes me.  Any hint/suggestion welcome.

Thank you

Maurice

Comment: This is a case where the exact wording "for all sufficiently large $n$" is your friend (in the definition of convergence in probability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that in order to show that $X_n \to 0$ in probability, you must show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) \to 0$.

Now go back to the definition of sequence convergence: you have to show that for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, we have $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) < \delta$.  Can you see how to choose such an $N$?  Keep in mind that $N$ is allowed to depend on both $\delta$ and $\epsilon$!

Comment: Yes,  thank you. I got your point.... I was just trying to get $P[X_n > \epsilon] = $ "something" and show that "something" as a function of $n $ goes to zero as n goes to infinity. But, as you (and Kimchi Lover earlier) pointed out, since limits are only defined for accumulation points and the only accumulation point for the integers is $+\infty, $ I can just apply the strict definition of limit, i.e. going for $n > \max\{\lfloor 1/\epsilon \rfloor + 1, \lfloor \delta^{-1/2}\rfloor +1\}..... $

Comment: @Maurice: You can of course determine $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ explicitly.  As you note there are two cases, but only one of them is relevant in computing the limit.  Another way to say it is that the sequence $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ looks something like $1, 1, \dots, 1, 1/k^2, 1/(k+1)^2, \dots$, i.e. it is $1$ up to some point and looks like $1/n^2$ thereafter.  The point at which it switches varies with $\epsilon$, but the limit is always zero no matter what.